# Laravel 5.4 file upload validation fails for python files

Tags: php, laravel, mime-types

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my validation, but I'm not sure.

I have created a file upload that uploads the file to S3. Works fine except when I need to validate python files.

In my `FileUploadController.php` I have a `store(FileStoreRequest $request)` method that handles the upload. I added the `$validatedData = $request->validate();` in it and it works.

I have also added the `mimes.php` in `config` folder with the following:

```php
<?php

return [
  'zip' => array('application/x-zip', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed'),
  'py' => array('text/plain', 'application/x-python' , 'application/octet-stream, application/x-python-code, text/x-python-script', 'text/x-python'),
];
```

And the `rules()` method inside my `FileStoreRequest` class is

```php
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'preprocessor' => 'mimes:py',
        ];
    }
```

Any time I try to upload the python file I get the error

> The preprocessor must be a file of type: py.

When I remove the mimes check from the `rules()` it passes.

The rules work, because I tested it on another view for zip file upload.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom validation like:

```
$input = $request->all();

if (isset($input["preprocessor"]) && !empty($input["preprocessor"])) {        
$filesource = $input["preprocessor"];
$fileExtension = $filesource->getClientOriginalExtension();
$input["ext"] = $fileExtension;
} 

$rules = array(
'ext' => 'nullable|in:py',
);
```

Comment: Hi! That's ok, but I was thinking of using the way it's usually done in Laravel, instead of doing my own checks :)